# Read resource under build (auto generated) folder in Android

Tags: android

In am converting json file to xml file at build time, location of xml file is under build folder. That is done successfully. Now i am trying to read content of that xml file, but not able to read it. When I check R.java file, it not contents those xml values. Any idea that how to make that folder as resource folder?[image]

Comment: I know that with generating Java code, you have to tell the Android Plugin for Gradle that you added Java code via `registerJavaGeneratingTask`. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/Staticizer), which generates Java code from a JSON object, akin to how `BuildConfig.java` is generated. There may be a similar `register...` for resources that you have to invoke.

Comment: Thanks commons ware,its helpful